# Is there an equivalent of GWT editors in JavaFX

Tags: gwt, javafx

[Editors](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html) are a very useful feature in GWT and I am looking for an equivalent in JavaFX.

Let's say that I have a bean called Person with following properties :

- name : String
- surname : String
- age : Integer

I can create an Editor called PersonEditor with following components :

- name : TextField (implements `Editor<String>`)
- surname : TextField (implements `Editor<String>`)
- age : IntegerField (implements `Editor<Integer>`)

Then a simple call to the editor allows me to update all UI Components :

```
Person p = new Person
p.setName("name");
p.setSurname("surname");
p.setAge(28):

personEditor.edit(p);  //Updates all graphical components :)

Person p = personEditor.flush() //Or commit all changes made by the user and give me back the bean.
```

Is there an equivalent in javaFX? It would avoid me to call each component one by one to set/get their values...

Comment: +1 Editors are fantastic in GWT and integrate really nicely with UiBinder, JSR-303 validation, RequestFactory... I've not seen anything as good elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no complete equivalent of GWT Editors in JavaFX 2.x core code, though you can get pretty similar functionality through a combination of the core JavaFX system and supplemental 3rd party libraries.

Of the 3rd party libraries available for JavaFX, [FXForm2](http://dooapp.github.io/FXForm2/) is probably the closest in functionality.

Core features to support some of the elements of GWT Editor like functionality are supplied in JavaFX, for example a [UIBinder](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) is a bit like an [FXMLLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html).  Virtual controls in JavaFX such as [TableViews](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) also provide similar functionality via [Cells with cell factories](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) and [PropertyValueFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) that introspects on plain old java objects to provide 2-way UI binding of elements.  And of course JavaFX has great built-in [property and binding facilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm).

ControlsFX provides the [PropertySheet](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.html) control for generating a UI form from a Java object.

Third party libraries can such as [JideFX](http://www.jidesoft.com/blog/2013/06/11/highlights-of-the-jidefx-beta-release-3-of-3/) provide form validation facilities.